# Coercing Dict to Read List as Tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have an existing `dict` that has keys but no values. I would like to populate the values by iterating over two lists at the same time like so:

```
for (pair,name) in enumerate(zip([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]], ['pair1','pair2','pair3','pair4','pair5','pair6'])):
    my_dict[tuple(name)] = pair
```

However I get the error: unhashable type: list.

So it seems my attempt to cast the list as a tuple doesn't work. I choose tuple because, according to what I read from other posts is a better way to go.

Can someone adjust this method to work as desired? I'm also open to other solutions.

**Update**

I will take the blame for not putting my whole function in the post. I thought being more concise would make things easier to understand, but in the end some important details were overlooked. Sorry for that. I'm working with `numpy` and `sklearn` Here is my whole function:

```
pair_names = ['pair1','pair2','pair3','pair4','pair5','pair6']
pair_dict = {p:[] for p in pair_names}
for (pair,key) in zip([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]], ['pair1','pair2','pair3','pair4','pair5','pair6']):
    x = iris.data[:,pair]
    y = iris.target
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x,y)
    decision_boundaries = decision_areas(clf,[0,7,0,3])
    pair_dict[key] = decision_boundaries
```

Going on the suggestions from the answers to this question so far, I removed `enumerate` and simply used `zip`. Unfortunately, now on the line `clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(x,y)` I get an error:number of samples does not match number of labels. Which I find odd, because I didnt change the sample size at all. My only guess is it has something to do with `enumerate` or `zip` -- because that is the only difference from the original function from the documentation example

Comment: have you checked what `enumerate(zip(...))` actually returns? It's not what you think it is.

Comment: A `list` is mutable and thus cannot be used as a dictionary key. If you try `my_dict={[1]:1}` you will get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Comment: @tobias_k thank you I did mix them up. I just noticed a few minutes ago myself. The post has been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you want is:

```
{ tuple(x):y for (x,y) in zip([[0,1],[0,2],[0,3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]], ['pair1','pair2','pair3','pair4','pair5','pair6'])}
```

Comment: thank you for this work-around, but I have some further issues if you would please refer to my updated post.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know `numpy` and `sklearn`, I can't help you further.

Comment: In all fairness, you did answer my original question. I found a way to resolve my issue by iterating a separate list that was out of scope, which simplified things enough for me to figure it out.